# moving a rectangle inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

my code :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var canvas,
    ctx,
    playerimage,
    x,
    y,
    speed = 5, //speed for the player to move at
    width = 10, //width of the player
    height = 10; //height of the player

    function init() {
        canvas = $("#Mycanvas");
        ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
        x = canvas.width() / 2;
        y = canvas.height() / 2;

         playerimage = new Image();
         playerimage.src = "ninja.png"; //path to the image to use for the player
         window.addEventListener("keydown", update, false);
        //canvas.addEventListener("keypress", update);
         render();
    }

    $(window).load(function () { init(); });

    function update(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 38) {
            y -= speed; //going up
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 40) {
            y += speed; //going down
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
            x -= speed; //going left
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 39) {
            x += speed; //going right
        }
        render();
    }

    function render() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);


    }
});
```

my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BLpGH/14/

as you can see the rectangle isn't moving instead the it seems like drawing a line stead of moving i don't want it to draw a line how can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working version under, and **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/R6Tx5/)**.

I moved the `clearRect` to the update function so it would run before values changed.
I added also `if` conditions so the `img` will not go out of the `canvas`.

```
   function update(event) {
       if (x + 20 > canvas.width() && event.keyCode == 39) {
           ctx.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
           x = canvas.width() - 15;
           render();
           return false;
       }
       if (x - 10 < 0 && event.keyCode == 37) {
           ctx.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
           x = 5;
           render();
           return false;
       }

       if (y - 10 < 0 && event.keyCode == 38) {
           ctx.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
           y = 5;
           render();
           return false;
       }
       if (y + 20 > canvas.height() && event.keyCode == 40) {
           ctx.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
           y = canvas.height() - 15;
           render();
           return false;
       }

       ctx.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
       if (event.keyCode == 38) {
           y -= speed; //going up
       }
       if (event.keyCode == 40) {
           y += speed; //going down
       }
       if (event.keyCode == 37) {
           x -= speed; //going left
       }
       if (event.keyCode == 39) {
           x += speed; //going right
       }
       render();
   }

   function render() {
       ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
   }
```

I use x + 20 because the square you defined is (width = 10, //width of the player). So if you are near the canvas end I wanted to guarantee that it's canvas - width of the player, but because x defined the left pixel of the square/player image, then I added 2x 10. In the oposite direction this in not necessary, so just 1x width is enough. Same with the y.

Comment: is there anyway to modify my code so when the rectangle hit can just animate withing the canvas border ?

Comment: @Sora, here is a working version, updated my answer also. -  http://jsfiddle.net/R6Tx5/

Comment: @Sora, good optimization! Looks like you know what you are doing, which part do you want me to explain?

Comment: the x and the y part and the calculation why for example if(x+20>canvas.width()) why 20 ?

Comment: @Sora, added a comment to that in my answer, at the bottom.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhh hehe i understand now thank u sorry i am not that good at math :P

Answer (score 1):

`canvas.width` and `canvas.height` are functions. Store them as vars or call `canvas.width()` and `canvas.height()`

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

...to this:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width(), canvas.height());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BLpGH/15/

That is, call `.width` and `.height` as functions. Though it would be more efficient to store these values in variables rather than having the two method calls every time you repaint.

Comment: can i modify my code and let the rectangle move withing the canvas ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not clearing the canvas correctly. The canvas variable is a jQuery object and width and height are function calls, not properties. Change this line

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width(), canvas.height());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project, for moving a rectangle inside a canvas, you can add, delete, any number of squares inside of canvas, You can get access to a public repository [here](https://github.com/abhijeetAbnave/MagicRectangle).

Besides, the live project you can see [here](https://magic-rectangle.herokuapp.com/).

[image]